# How to call a Non API Controller function using Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have controller, and it's name is "AuthController" which is being inherited by "BaseController". "AuthController" has a parametric constructor as well a method "RegisterFromOutside" that is being used to register the user. Below code work fine for the Non Api Controller.

Code Sample for Non Api Controller:

[image]

Now the question is how can I use the API controller to call the same method? and then access it from my mobile application (using the same implementations). Please note that project doesn't have any implementation for API calling yet.

This is when is am getting this error. and the error is

"But when i tried to access the same UserServices from the other Web API application controller with Parametric constructor. It asks me to declare parameter-less constructor. and when i do that it simply don't run the parametric constructor and in return i receive null reference exception."

```cs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        UserServices _userServices;

        public ValuesController(
            UserServices userServices)
        {
            _userServices = userServices;
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            RegisterFromOutside(model);
        }

        public void RegisterFromOutside(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            User user = _userServices.Register(model.Username, model.Password, model.Email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. do not post code as images 2. why you wana this class ? you have already `UserServices` ... 3. define *access it from my mobile application* - does it mean mobile app is written in C# and use the same code or mobile app needs to acces it via HTTP

Comment: Sorry for the image in question. But when i tried to access the same UserServices from the other Web API application controller with Parametric constructor. It asks me to declare parameter-less constructor. and when i do that it simply don't run the parametric constructor and in return i receive null reference exception.

Comment: Yes Everything is in C#. All i need to create a WebApi for the "RegisterFromOutside" Method so that i can use it over web.

Comment: AuthController is inheriting BaseController….not the other way around? Why not inherit AuthController in you API controller rather than inheriting BaseController?

Comment: Not possible two inherit two classes at a time. I need to inherit ApiController as well.

Comment: I have updated the question a bit. Please have a look.

Comment: Sounds as if the problem lies with how you instantiate the UserServices object. Could you please edit your question to show how this is done in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can add API controller in MVC project(right click on folder Controllers, choose Add 
 --> Controller)

[image: adding api controller]

There is method signature in my project, which executes user authorization, you can do the same thing(you can also try to do that in classic non-API controller)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/mobile/users/login")]
        public LoginResponseModel Login(LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel)
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I have updated the question a bit. Please a look.